# Is it possible for flutter to get the browser url when a url is launched in an in-app-browser?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, oauth, fitbit

I am trying to connect the FitbitAPI to my flutter-firebase application. However, whenever I authenticate my account it doesn't redirect back to my application. I used the Implicit Grant Flow since I am not working with a server to power my backend. However, I do not have a way to get the token written in the browser url. An example of this is :

> https://MYFIREBASEPROJECT.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.egfhwerqwjehqwkjehkashdaadadsadybG9jIHJ3ZW123123123sdsadsaasdasdagcnBybyByc2xlIiwiZXhwIjoxNTczMjk5ODQ2LCJpYXQiOjE1NzI2OTUwNDZ9.axlEiYsVicy6l-aEbphcqZlr3bHXUxq6hV2ky5o_3qw&user_id=7SFL86&scope=social+location+weight+nutrition+activity+sleep+settings+heartrate+profile&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=604800

I would like a way for me to get the last url from an in-app web browser. The in-app-browser package I use is [web_browser](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_browser)

Answer (score 1):

With that package , no.

You could use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin wich allows you to launch a webview inside your app , and have full control of it.

Or you could use your package or https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher to launch an external browser wich you don't control, but redirect to a deeplink that opens your app and handle it with https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links

So both methods are possible

EDIT:

A brief explanation of how a deeplink works.

Most of the urls start with "http://", that tells the browser to open a webpage with the domain of the url. However, if you use other start of the url , the browser does different things. In android per example if you type `whatsapp://app` in your browser url and launch it, it will launch the whatsapp app. The same can be done for your app oauth. The only thing you will need to implement it is configure your android app. The brief concept can be found [here](https://medium.com/@muratcanbur/intro-to-deep-linking-on-android-1b9fe9e38abd) , but to communicate the android app deeplink with flutter you need uni_links , they also provide a tutorial in their package page.  You can find a tutorial for flutter [HERE](https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283)

Comment: Thanks I might try the web-view so that I can do my API calls dynamically. Can you provide more information on how deeplink works? This is a new concept for me. thank you for your answer!